# remove rows in one column based on duplicated values in another column in R (remove specific raws)

Tags: r, duplicates

In my dataset I have two columns.
POINT: contains only two categorical values 'random' and 'current' repeated all over the dataset.
ID: contains a set of 5-digit continuous values associated to the values in POINT. Some of the values in ID are repeated.

I cannot figure out a code in R to eliminate ONLY the raws that have duplicated values in the ID column when the POINT value is 'random' when compared to 'current'. So I would like the below dataset :

| POINT | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Current | 45905 |
| Current | 40817 |
| Current | 55936 |
| Current | 66608 |
| Current | 66608 |
| Random | 45905 |
| Random | 40817 |
| Random | 55936 |
| Random | 66608 |
| Random | 44456 |

to look like this:

| POINT | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Current | 45905 |
| Current | 40817 |
| Current | 55936 |
| Current | 66608 |
| Current | 66608 |
| Random | 44456 |

Comment: sorry I missed something in the coding for the second table, hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! I don't quite understand this part of your question: " when the POINT value is 'random' when compared to 'current'." Do you mean when, for a duplicated ID, you have two Point value: random and current?

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `dpylr` this could be achieved like so:

1. Split your data by `POINT`
2. Filter non-duplicated IDs in the random part using an `anti_join`
3. Rowbind the filtered random dataset to the current dataset.

```r
d <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             POINT = c("Current","Current","Current",
                       "Current","Current","Random","Random","Random",
                       "Random","Random"),
                ID = c(45905L,40817L,55936L,66608L,
                       66608L,45905L,40817L,55936L,66608L,44456L)
)

d_split <- split(d, d$POINT)

library(dplyr)

random_keep <- dplyr::anti_join(d_split$Random, d_split$Current, by = "ID")
d_final <- dplyr::bind_rows(d_split$Current, random_keep)

head(d_final)
#>     POINT    ID
#> 1 Current 45905
#> 2 Current 40817
#> 3 Current 55936
#> 4 Current 66608
#> 5 Current 66608
#> 6  Random 44456
```

Comment: Hi, thanks actually this code was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you could use `dplyr` to do this:

```
library(dplyr)

split_data <- split(your_data, ~ POINT)

full_join(split_data$Current, split_data$Random, by = "ID") %>%
  transmute(POINT = coalesce(POINT.x, "Random"), ID)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  POINT      ID
  <chr>   <int>
1 Current 45905
2 Current 40817
3 Current 55936
4 Current 66608
5 Current 66608
6 Random  44456
```

(Data used:)

```
your_data <- structure(list(POINT = c("Current", "Current", "Current", "Current", "Current", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random", "Random"), ID = c(45905L, 40817L, 55936L, 66608L, 66608L, 45905L, 40817L, 55936L, 66608L, 44456L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the negated `%in%` to exclude duplicated ID for `POINT==random`.

```
i <- D$POINT=="Current"
D[i | !D$ID %in% D$ID[i],]
#     POINT    ID
#1  Current 45905
#2  Current 40817
#3  Current 55936
#4  Current 66608
#5  Current 66608
#10  Random 44456
```

Data:

```
D <- data.frame(POINT = c("Current","Current","Current","Current","Current"
  ,"Random","Random","Random","Random","Random")
, ID = c(45905L,40817L,55936L,66608L,66608L,45905L,40817L,55936L,66608L,44456L))
```